# C# Convert Json array to string array using Json.Net

Tags: arrays, json, string

I'm currently writing a little toolbox for a game, which also has a Twitch viewer. I'm stuck at getting information using the Twitch Web API.
[Search streamers playing Hearthstone](https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?limit=100&offset=0&Hearthstone&q=Hearthstone)

As you can see, after some values, there is an array called "streams" and I need to put the data in this array in a variable or such (maybe using foreach). So it should do this:

```
foreach(var arrayElement in JArray thisArray){
    //do stuff
}
```

So what I need exactly, is getting a list of names, who is streaming a specified game and I'm using JSON for it.
Is there something like this, or do I have to do it completely different?

Please let me know quick

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var stringArray = thisArray.ToObject<string[]>();
```